# AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh resolution on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, avfoundation

I need to know what the AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh resolution is for the newest iPad, and for all various devices for that matter. Apple's documentation has a chart that explains what the various resolutions are for the different presets, but only for the iPhone 3, 3GS, and 4. That chart is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html

Is there somewhere else where this is recorded for the rest of the devices? I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh and with iPad 4 it returns me the resolution of 1280x720!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I tested with iPad 3 (Retina) and it returns 1280x720.

BTW, the AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh is the default for AVCaptureSession.